Why would Mysql return "error Column cannot be null"?
We recently moved our mysql version to mysql 8 but we are facing a really strange behavior some (valid) queries that would work before like a charm stopped working (sometimes) for no reason and mysql return an error but if we re-run it sometimes it works.
Here's an example :
UPDATE `Members` set `ProZipCode` = 75001, `ProCity` = 'Paris', `ActivationCode` = 'AAA-15372695', `State` = 1 WHERE `MemberId` = 42;

If i run this query 10 times in a row it will work like 6 times but 4 times it would throw an error (randomly) both in Laravel or in phpmyadmin :
Integrity constraint violation : Column 'ActivationCode' cannot be null 

We are using mysql version 8.0.36
Edit with some asked clarification :

The mysql version is 8.0.36
The field 'ActivationCode' is a classic varchar(255) NOT NULL column
There is no foreign key or so in the table, there is only one before insert trigger to generete a MemberHash, no event, lock or whatever else
I'm running the exact same query manually 10 times in a row on phpmyadmin or via an API call (with the same data)
The ActivationCode is not auto-generated, i'm updating it in the query
The database is hosted on Google Cloud SQL there are 3 flags : log_bin_trust_function_creators (on) , sql_mode (NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION, ALLOW_INVALID_DATES), explicit_default_for_timestamp(off)
Other servers are on cloud run
Of course I could just change the column to accept null value but that's not possible since this error occurs on multiple column/table


You need to show the creation schemea for the table.  Are there any triggers, events, locks, or foreign keys?  Is it a remote database so its possible some latency is to blame?

But the error indicates that at some point, perhaps due to latency or other errors, what ever is generating the activation code value was not getting the value in time to be inserted in the statement and thus it passed nothing and threw the error?  It is actually a good thing the error triggers too as if the column was not set to deny null values, it would of overwritten the value in that column with null.

When you run it 10 times in a row, are you using the same value fo ActivationCode? If the code is being generated dynamically, some of them may be null.

How are you running the query 10 times in a row from PhpMyAdmin?

There is no MySQL version 8.2.20. Please run SELECT VERSION(); and confirm what version you are really using.

Hey, I edited the intial post to include some context and answer to your questions

Can you show the CREATE TABLE and the trigger?

I can't show you the create table, the trigger is as follow :
CREATE TRIGGER GenerateMemberHash BEFORE INSERT ON Members
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.MemberHash = RANDSTRING(32)
Also I really don't think it's related to a particular column or table, we have the same problem randomly on different column/table and it worked for years before we switched to mysql8 and Google Cloud

It seems downgrading to the latest mysql 5.7 version fixed our problem. We tried upgrading to the latest mysql 8 version but it didn't worked.
A really strange behaviour ...
